# añadir clase a un elemento al hacer scroll hacia abajo y eliminar al hacer scroll hacia arriba con Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, scroll

Estoy intentando cambiar el color de fondo de mi `navbar` (menu)cuando hago *scroll* hacia abajo y devolverla a su estado original cuando hago scroll hacia arriba y entra en el primer componente (que es la portada) se que tengo que añadir una clase y eliminarla, se que si no estuviera en Angular sería "facil" hacerlo con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), pero en angular no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Lo conseguí con:

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", []) onWindowScroll() {}
```

de Angular